# Join on 3 columns with problematic 3rd column

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, I need to **join** two tables on three columns. The first two columns, C1 and C2 will always match.
The third column (c3) in table_1 either has a numeric value or is null/blank.
If table_1.C3 has a value, no problem - it should match table_2.C3.
If table_1.C3 is null, it needs to match table_2.C3 with an '*'.

I cannot find logic that will return the null/* matching records. I am only getting results for those records where C3 is numeric and matching in both columns.

I don't care of the join criteria is in the 'join...on...' clause or if it is in the 'where' criteria. Either one works for me.

I have tried some complicated, lengthy logic and I have tried a 'where...case...' but don't understand the latter, yet.

Thanks!

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.desc
from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 = t2.c2 and t1.c3...???
```

Table_1 (T1):

```
C1  C2  C3
--- --  --
300 01  30 
300 01  32 
300 02     
300 04  01 
300 04  02 
300 04  14 
300 04
```

Table_2 (T2):

```
C1  C2  C3  Desc
--- --  --  -----
300 01  30  Desc1
300 01  32  Desc2
300 02  *   Desc3
300 04  *   Desc4
300 04  01  Desc5
300 04  02  Desc6
300 04  14  Desc7
300 04  21  Desc8
300 04  30  Desc9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `on` condition to ensure a match:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.desc
from table_1 t1 join
     table_2 t2
     on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and
        t1.c2 = t2.c2 and
        (t1.c3 = t2.c3 or t1.c3 is null and t2.c3 = '*');
```